# SSIS's job validation error

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I've created a SSIS package in my workstation.
It worked until the very last minute when I moved it to the Server machine (the NT user is the same on both desktops PC, mine)

The protection level is set to `EncryptSensitiveWithPassword`.

Here's the output error coming out from job-running-atempts.

```
    Error: 2012-08-17 11:57:04.74
   Code: 0xC0202009
   Source: CCTSQLBajadas Connection manager "MyPackage"
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'COMPANY\TTP321$'.".
End Error
Error: 2012-08-17 11:57:04.76
   Code: 0xC020801C
   Source: call view populate replace [157] //name of one the steps inside the package.
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "MyPackage" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
End Error
```

What's weird for me is the line `Login failed for user 'COMPANY\TTP321$` Because COMPANY is the Network and TTP321 is server's hostname. Shouldn't it be my NT username? Since the conections used in the package are all under my username. And of course, it won't validate if it tries to do `COMPANY\TTP321$`

Any idea on where the package is trying to run using that special username?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that COMPANY\TTP321$ has access to that database?

Comment: it does not (company\ttp321$) doesn't even exist), the correct user is COMPANY\MyUserName. That's how it's set in the SSIS package. I'm not sure why the scheduled job is trying to access that way.

Comment: I would guess that TTP321$ is the domain account that SQLAgent is running under.  You'll need to set the account that your package is running under in SQLAgent, not in your package.

Comment: Bingo! now it's working. Please submit this as an answer so you get the credit and hopefuly it may help people in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COMPANY\TTP321$ is the userid that SQLAgent is running under, so your package is also running with that user's permissions.  If you want to run under your user name, you need to set that up in SQLAgent.